# How can I efficiently stream large data from SQL Server 2008 to a web browser?

Tags: c#, sql-server, binarystream

I'm using C# and ASP.NET MVC 3. Currently, I'm taking a large set of data from SQL Server, adding it into a `StringBuilder`, and then using `System.Text.ASCIIEncoding` to convert the `StringBuilder` object to a `byte[]` array.

I then send the `byte[]` array to the view. However, the amount of data is so large, I get the following exception:

> Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown

Here's the code that I use in my controller to convert the `StringBuilder` object to `byte[]` and then return to the view. Is there a way to stream the data straight from the database to the client browser without loading it all up in memory on the server first?

```
System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
return File(encoding.GetBytes(csv.ToString()), "text/csv", "Query_Export.csv");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something similar to the following pseudo code

```
  while (sqlReader.GetBytes(params))//params is a placeholder for the actual arguments and
                                    //will have a byte array buffer and some counter indexes
  {
      context.Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
      //somecounter
  }
```

SqlDataReader
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks for the quick response.  I'm going to give this a shot.